# How to install 'pygraphviz' through anaconda

Tags: anaconda, graphviz

I tried outputting one of my DiGraphs as follows:
`A=nx.drawing.nx_agraph.to_agraph(Graph)`
nx.drawing.nx_agraph.write_dot(dot_filename)

However I got :

> ImportError: ('requires pygraphviz ', 'http://pygraphviz.github.io/')

Anaconda command windows says

> graphviz  2.38.0  0  is already installed..

Can anybody help who managed to use Graphviz through Anaconda?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
conda install -c pdrops pygraphviz=1.2
```

Comment: It did not work. It returned that "package missing in current win-64 channels".

Answer (score 0):

Check conda pygraphviz package availability for your system. Previous answer seems to be a package available just for linux & osx 64. Give a try to

```
conda install -c marufr pygraphviz=1.3.1
```

this version shows in the details to be compatible with win32 & 64 as well as with linux and osx. You can find more packages from any user typing

```
conda install -c binstar binstar
```

Afterthat, for instance, to find all the pygraphviz packages in public channels code

```
binstar search -t conda pygraphviz
```

Finally find your platform compatible and install from command line as usual.

Comment: I installed Graphviz using the channel you specified at the top and run a couple of simple  Graphviz commands, it resulted with an import error as follows: no _graphviz module exists. Then I installed binstar, this time I encountered another import error: cannot import name get_server_api

Comment: One kind soul has uploaded pygraphviz 1.5dev-py36_0 for windows to anaconda. `conda install -c alubbock pygraphviz`